# Is it possible to run concurrent selenium test Suits against single Grid Hub?

Tags: selenium, grid, selenium-grid

**Hey all**
Is it possible to run concurrent selenium test Suits against single Grid Hub?
If yes is there any special configuration I need to set in order to enable it? If no is there any workaround you can think about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the question: 
PC 1 : Test Suite 1
PC 2 : Test Suite 2
PC 3 : Selenium Grid Hub

Both PC 1 and PC 2 use PC 3 as a hub for their test suites execution.

But you haven't mentioned anything about the Nodes here.

Assuming PC 3 itself is the Node. And you have set your maxSession and maxInstances properly as per your test suites require, then the tests will run fine.

Please provide more information regarding the Node and the command/script you use to create the Nodes and Hub if you need further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, yes, this is the intention of grid.  You can send as many concurrent test requests to the hub as you wish and the hub will distribute the requests to appropriate nodes, holding pending tests for an available node.

As far as configuration, you'll want to check out the wiki ( https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2 ) for full info, but specific configuration you are interested in is:

"maxSession": the number of parallel instances that can be run on the node/hub

Comment: It's not what I meant. I know that a single test suit contains multiple tests that are able to run concurrently in a "grid mode".
My question is what will happen if you execute a test suite from your computer and I am executing another test suit from another computer and we both use the same Grid-Hub what will happen?

Comment: I believe my answer is responding to what you asked.  A test suite is just a test request consisting of multiple tests.  A major reason for the existence of grid is for multiple test efforts to send test requests to the grid, this can and usually does mean many users sending concurrent requests.  The hub distributes the tests across applicable nodes for execution.  In our operation we have some 60+ people all sending test suites to the hub all day every day.